# That came despite an international agreement... - meaning, grammar

Tags: meaning, grammar

Source: http://news.yahoo.com/foreign-military-observers-held-east-ukraine-114040788.html

> Ukraine's acting president this week ordered security forces to resume operations in the country's east after the bodies of two people allegedly abducted by pro-Russia insurgents were found and a military aircraft was reported to have been hit by gunfire.
>
> **That came despite** an international agreement calling for all sides in Ukraine to refrain from violence and for demonstrators to vacate public buildings. It did not specifically prohibit security operations, but Ukraine suspended an earlier so-called "anti-terrorist operation" after the accord.

I don't know how to understand the phrase in bold.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace "That"

with

"The President's order"

Comment: I agree with Gary.  If we wanted to keep "that", it should have been "That order came..." (meaning The President's order, as Gary stated)  +Gary

Answer (score 1):

What the author is trying to say is that Ukraine's president's order to remobilize security forces occurred although the international community had agreed upon peace.
"That came despite" could most nearly be replaced by "this occurred although".